# Why can't I connect to ElasticSearch through Java API?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm having trouble connecting to vanilla ElasticSearch cluster via the Java API.

To reproduce:

```
#start elasticsearch
elasticsearch -f

#checking in a new window
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1' -d '{\
    "user" : "kimchy",\
    "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",\
    "message" : "trying out Elastic Search"\
}'
```

result:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "_index": "twitter",
  "_type": "tweet",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 3
}
```

---

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search?q=user:kimchy'
```

result:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.30685282,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "twitter",
        "_type": "tweet",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.30685282,
        "_source": {
          "user": "kimchy",
          "post_date": "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
          "message": "trying out Elastic Search"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So, everything works via HTTP. Trying via Java (per [this page](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/java-api/client/)):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Client client = new TransportClient()
    .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9200));

    IndexResponse response = null;
    try {
      response = client.prepareIndex("twitter", "tweet", "1")
          .setSource(XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
                      .startObject()
                          .field("user", "john")
                          .field("postDate", new Date())
                          .field("message", "who dont it work")
                      .endObject()
                    )
          .execute()
          .actionGet();
    } catch (ElasticSearchException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(response);
}
```

And I get the following stack trace:

```
May 21, 2013 8:27:42 AM org.elasticsearch.plugins
INFO: [Bes] loaded [], sites []
May 21, 2013 8:27:49 AM org.elasticsearch.client.transport
INFO: [Bes] failed to get node info for [#transport#-1][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]], disconnecting...
org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]][cluster/nodes/info] request_id [0] timed out after [5002ms]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:342)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:202)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClient.execute(InternalTransportClient.java:106)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.index(AbstractClient.java:84)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.index(TransportClient.java:310)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequestBuilder.doExecute(IndexRequestBuilder.java:315)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:62)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:57)
    at Scratch.main(Scratch.java:30)
```

And closest thing I've found so far to this problem is [here](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/No-node-available-Exception-td3920119.html), but the thread trailed off without resolution.

Comment: I am getting the following error while using elastic search can you help @jnBrymn Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty3Plugin overrides final method onModule.(Lorg/elasticsearch/common/network/NetworkModule;)V

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The TransportClient default port is 9300. You have to use it instead of 9200 in your Java code. This is probably why the connection fails.

Comment: And... that did it! The elasticsearch example has 9300. They should change that I guess.

Comment: I'm apparently very confused. I checked back at that example and indeed it's 9200. So... I imagined it!

Comment: updated: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/java-api/client/ the TransportClient example, uses the 9300 port

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import org.elasticsearch.action.get.GetResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient;


public class ElasticsearchTest {  
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws UnknownHostException{ 

        /* //Set new cluester
        Settings settings = Settings.builder()
                .put("cluster.name", "newCluster")
                .put("node.name","newNode").build();*/

        //create cliet !!!Make sure keep settings empty if your cluster is the 
        //same as the one you defined in your elasticsearch.yml file
        //Plus, port here（9300）must be different from your http port(9200)

        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));
        //get data
        GetResponse response = client.prepareGet("twitter", "tweet", "1").execute().actionGet();

       //output
        System.out.println(response.getSourceAsString());

        client.close(); 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: please explain or add some comments to your code, it will be more helpful for learners.