# ElasticSearch giving ReceiveTimeoutTransportException

Tags: java, curl, elasticsearch

Hi I am trying to connect my ElasticSearch Client to my localhost and trying to get the indices from there.

```
import org.elasticsearch.action.get.GetResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.node.Node;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.*;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import static org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder;
public class ESClient
{
    public static void search()throws IOException
    {
        Node node;
        node = nodeBuilder().clusterName("elasticsearch").node();
        Client client;
        client= new TransportClient()
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9200));
        GetResponse response;
        response= client.prepareGet("twitter", "tweet", "1").execute() .actionGet();
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        search();

    }

}
```

I have created the indices using the terminal.

> curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/' curl -XPUT
>   'http://localhost:9200/twitter/_mapping/tweet' -d ' {
>       "tweet" : {
>           "properties" : {
>               "message" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true }
>           }
>       }                                          }                            '

When I am executing it, the following error is thrown,

> NFO: [Blackheath] failed to get node info for
>   [#transport#-1][BLRMCB-C02L56J4DR53.local][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]],
>   disconnecting...
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException:
>   [][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]][cluster:monitor/nodes/info]
>   request_id [0] timed out after [5002ms]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:366)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of
>   the configured nodes are available: []    at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:278)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:197)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClient.execute(InternalTransportClient.java:106)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.get(AbstractClient.java:193)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.get(TransportClient.java:384)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.action.get.GetRequestBuilder.doExecute(GetRequestBuilder.java:201)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:91)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:65)
>     at ....ESClient.search(ESClient.java:30)    at
>   ....ESClient.main(ESClient.java:36)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

What is the problem, can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I switched from using an ElasticSearchAdapter for queries to a SparkStreamingAdapter for the same queries. I had to change the port to 9300, and then this error did not appear.

This question/answer helped me figure this out:
[Why can't I connect to ElasticSearch through Java API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670219/why-cant-i-connect-to-elasticsearch-through-java-api)